# When do I use non-, ir-/i-, dis-, a-, or un-?

Tags: negation, prefixes, morphology

Between using the prefixes *non-*, *ir-*, *i-*, and *dis-*, *a-*, or *un-*, meaning "*not (root word)* to do something", when is the best time to use each?

Comment: Consult a dictionary.  Or do you mean: how should you invent your own words?

Comment: @GEdgar -- well, I'm not trying to invent a word, but a particular word I looked up had multiple prefixes, ended with the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use each prefix with the words that can take that prefix. I'm sorry, but that is the whole of the answer.

There are tendencies which might help (for example, *in-* and its variants *il-* and *ir-* are only used with words of Latin origin, *a-* with words of Greek origin, and *un-* mostly with words of Germanic origin. But even if you know the origins of words, these rules are not reliable.

Comment: Germans seem to experience particular difficulty in choosing the right ones. I had a colleague whom I swear used to toss a coin, and would talk about things being *unpossible*, and *inofficial*. In other respects he would speak faultless English.